# How to read into byte array file contents and then update them and write into another file?

Tags: nsis

I want in nsis to be able to read from file contents into byte array, update the array and then write the contents of the buffer into another file.

My Code

```
System::Call "kernel32::GetFileSize(i$0,i0)i.s"
Pop $7

System::Alloc $7  ;Reading file contents into a buffer
Pop $buffer
System::Call "kernel32::ReadFile(i$0,i$buffer,i$7,*i.r6,i0)i.s"

loop2:
        StrCpy $2 $buffer 1 $1
        StrCmp $2 '' end
        IntOp $1 $1 + 1

goto loop2
```

I wanted to be able to iterate over the byte array that i read from the file and to be able to change its contents. (OR bytes for instance) and i wanted to save time from reading byte from a file directly and then writing single byte to a new file. So thats why wanted to use buffer byte array allocated.
Is that possible? I saw that nsis does not support arrays natively.

Comment: You have asked a bunch of questions and not marked any of them as answered, why should I bother answering your question here?

Comment: Hi @Anders, it was not intentional. I will fix this immediately. Is there any way to mark comments as "answered"?

Comment: You mark answers as answered if they are correct. If they are not correct you should add a comment and try to get a working solution in the end.

Comment: Thanks @Anders. I will make sure that i take care of the mentioned above.. Do you have if it is possible to achieve what i asked in a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS does not support byte arrays but the System plug-in struct syntax allows you to access raw bytes in a memory buffer:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Util.nsh
ShowInstDetails show

!macro DisplayTestFile
FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\Test.txt" r
FileRead $0 $1
FileClose $0
DetailPrint Line1=$1
!macroend

Section
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\Test.txt" w
${If} $0 P<> 0
    FileWrite $0 "HELLO World$\r$\n"
    FileClose $0
${EndIf}

!insertmacro DisplayTestFile

FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\Test.txt" a
${If} $0 P<> 0
    FileSeek $0 0 Set
    System::Call "KERNEL32::GetFileSize(pr0,p0)i.r1"
    ${IfThen} $1 = -1 ${|} Abort "Could not get file size" ${|}
    System::Call '*(&i$1,i0)p.r2' ; Allocate the file size + a zero terminator just in case
    ${If} $2 P<> 0
        System::Call "KERNEL32::ReadFile(pr0,pr2,ir1,*i,p0)i.r3"
        ${If} $3 <> 0
            ${For} $3 0 5 ; Change byte 0..5
                System::Call '*$2(&i$3,&i1.r4)' ; Read a byte
                IntOp $4 $4 | 32
                System::Call '*$2(&i$3,&i1 r4)' ; Write a byte
            ${Next}
            FileSeek $0 0 Set
            System::Call "KERNEL32::WriteFile(pr0,pr2,ir1,*i,p0)i.r3"
        ${EndIf}
        System::Free $2
    ${EndIf}
    FileClose $0
${EndIf}

!insertmacro DisplayTestFile
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks @Anders. The code works like a charm. One question though. If i test a file that is 1 Megabyte to iterate over the buffer it takes a long time. Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: No, not with the System plug-in (plug-in call overhead + text parsing) for single byte access. If you actually need to OR then you could do it on 4 bytes at the time instead of 1 (&1 becomes &4 and increment the offset by 4 in the loop). The NSIS file instructions that read/write a byte are faster but still not super fast. The only way to make it super fast is to write your own plug-in for this specific task. You could then map the file into memory and change its contents directly with raw memory access.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it.